# I am creating cookie on 2nd domain by using 1st domain . its not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I am using ajax with PHP
I want to create cookie on ajax calling page
i have tow domain
like
`domain1.com` and `domain2.com`
i have done ajax code on `domain1.com` in page `test1.php`
And Create Cookie on `domain2.com` page `test.php`

test1.php /// domain1.php

```
$.ajax({
         url:domain2.com/test.php,
         type:post,
         datatype:json,
         data:'uname=test',
         success:function(data){
          if(data=='ok'){
                 window.location='http://domain2.com/cookietest.php'
                }
          }
      });
```

test.php ///// domain2.com

```
$uname=$_POST['uname'];
if($uname=='test'){
    setcookie('testcookie',$uname,time()+3600);
    echo 'ok';
}else{
      echo 'not'
     }
```

I checked cookie value on `domain2.com`

cookietest.php ///// domain2.com

```
<?php
    var_dump($_COOKIE);
?>
```

I did not found created cookie details.
can anyone help me

Comment: You know that cookies are most of the time domain connected

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies

Comment: OK thanks. but i Don't get my solution

Answer (score 0):

Since you are too lazy to read a link I provide you:

**.htaccess domain 1:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain2.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

**.htaccess domain 2:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain1.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Comment: Thanks.I have read this link and i also do this step but its not working